# JQuery JSONP ajax call to WCF triggers both error and callback function

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf, jsonp

This is really strange and I've tried to find the solution but havent been sucessfull, even after reading bunch of pages and tried out bunch of examples so here it is, even if this might be a duplicate question.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function JsonPCallBack(result) {
        console.log('success');
        console.log(result);
         $(result).each(function (index, value) {  
                $("#TableID").append("<tr><td>" + value.SymbolName + "</td><td>" + value.BidPrice + "</td><td>" + value.AskPrice + "</td></tr>");  
            });  
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#btnRefresh').on('click', function (event) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                url: "http://wcfhostwebsite.dev/Service.svc/GetLatestSymbolData?method=JsonPCallBack",
                error: function (error) {
                    if (error.status != "200") {
                        console.log("error");
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                }
            });
        });


    });
</script> 


</head>
<body>
<button id="btnRefresh">Refresh</button>
<form id="form1" runat="server">  
        <table id="TableID" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1"  width="400px" >  
            <tr>  
                <td style="background-color: green; color:white">SymbolName</td>  
                <td style="background-color: green; color:white">BidPrice</td>  
                <td style="background-color: green; color:white">AskPrice</td>  
            </tr>  
        </table>  
    </form>  
 
</body>
</html>
```

Even if I get proper response from WCF service (see below) and callback function is triggered it still triggers the error.

```
JsonPCallBack( {"AskPrice":125.77778,"BidPrice":123.44557,"SymbolDate":"\/Date(1415142000000+0100)\/","SymbolName":"EUR"} );
```

I've added a workaround to check the status, but I am not happy with this.

Please advise?